# is there a way for the contents on TextView will not disappear even after relaunching the app?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have this app i'm experimenting on. wherein the user will input data, saves it onto sharedpreferences and displays it. I already manage to do those three. except when relaunching the app. the details that should still be displayed on Textview disappears. is there a way for it not to disappear after relaunching?
[saved and displayed before relaunching the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eboBu.png)
[after relaunching the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOoVw.png)

Ps. I'm a beginner on android studio

Comment: do you want to show sample data on text view or user's saved data on relaunch ?

Comment: try to always add your code so that others can access where it's getting wrong then guessing what you might have done.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow !

If you have saved data in [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) then you simply need use `setText()` on text view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //your global variables here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        //some more textView  or other views initialization here

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //get saved value from SharedPreferences
        String saveText = sharedPreferences.getString("PREFERENCE_KEY", defaultValue);
        //some more saved value in similar manner

        //set saved value on TextView
        textView.setText(saveText);
    }
}
```

As `onCreate()` method will execute on every launch of app so as `textView.setText(saveText)`.

Now for the very first install of app,there is no data will be saved in SharedPreferences so `sharedPreferences.getString()` will use defaultValue you have provied.

If you just want to show some sample data on TextView on each startup, then you can `android:text="sample_data_value"` in your layout xml file as follow-

```
<TextView
    .......
    android:text="sample_data_value"/>
```

Happy Coding !

Comment: I've already manage to do that part and display it. I want to display the saved data every startup. do i need to create an argument for that to reoccur every startup?

Comment: no you simply need to use information saved in the Shared Preference and use `setText()` method on your text view, if you see that's what I did in my answer under `onCreate() ` method, please check again

Comment: thanks a lot. it got me a bit confused for a moment. but it worked out.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?) for more information